# Why is my HTML canvas not rotating?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Canvas script:

```
function clock_hand_hh(hh) {
    var hh_canvas = document.getElementById('clock_hand_hh');
    var hh_context = hh_canvas.getContext('2d');
    hh_canvas.width = 500;
    hh_canvas.height = 500;
    var centerX = hh_canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = hh_canvas.height / 2;
    var radius = 10;

    hh_context.beginPath();
    hh_context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    hh_context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    hh_context.fill();
    hh_context.lineWidth = 5;
    hh_context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    hh_context.stroke();

    hh_context.beginPath();
    hh_context.bezierCurveTo(centerX, centerY, centerX - 10, centerY - 50, centerX, centerY - 100);
    hh_context.bezierCurveTo(centerX, centerY-100, centerX + 10, centerY - 50, centerX, centerY);
    hh_context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    hh_context.fill();
    hh_context.lineWidth = 2;
    hh_context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    hh_context.stroke();   

    if (hh > 12) {
        hh = hh - 12;
    }
    //alert((hh / 12) * 2 * Math.PI);
    hh_context.translate(centerX, centerY);
    hh_context.rotate((hh / 12) * 2 * Math.PI); 
}
```

Note: The alert(which I commented) is showing the correct value of angle of rotation required (in radians) for canvas.

Comment: the html canvas is not rotating because you are only rotating the context. do as @LaxmikantDange says.

Comment: I want the whole canvas (everything in it) to be rotated, using center of canvas as reference.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange: Don't add code snippet functionality to questions like these that lack code to make the snippet work.

Comment: @Cerbrus, why you just remove snippet? Why not try to add html part?

Comment: @vp_arth: Because it's not the editor's job to add code to the question.

Comment: Is the HTML markup really necessary?

Comment: Html part need just for snippet correct working

Comment: It's just one line of HTML(<canvas id="#clock_hand_hh"></canvas>)
Note: hh= hours, a numerical value, if not obvious already

Comment: offtop: `hh = hh % 12 + 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just move it twice: you draw using `center` variables, and then move coordinates also...

```js
    function clock_hand_hh(hh) {
        var hh_canvas = document.getElementById('clock_hand_hh');
        var hh_context = hh_canvas.getContext('2d');
        hh_canvas.width = 500;
        hh_canvas.height = 500;
        var centerX = hh_canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = hh_canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 10;

        hh_context.translate(centerX, centerY);
        hh_context.rotate((hh / 12) * 2 * Math.PI); 

        hh_context.beginPath();
        hh_context.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        hh_context.fillStyle = '#000000';
        hh_context.fill();
        hh_context.lineWidth = 5;
        hh_context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        hh_context.stroke();


        hh_context.beginPath();
        hh_context.bezierCurveTo(0, 0, -10, -50, 0, -100);
        hh_context.bezierCurveTo(0, -100, 10, -50, 0, 0);
        hh_context.fillStyle = '#000000';
        hh_context.fill();
        hh_context.lineWidth = 2;
        hh_context.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        hh_context.stroke();   

        if (hh > 12) {
            hh = hh % 12 + 1;
        }
        //alert((hh / 12) * 2 * Math.PI);
    }

clock_hand_hh(4);
```

```html
<canvas id="clock_hand_hh" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you translate or rotate context it means you move and rotate the coordinate system with which you want to work. It does not affect the image already drawn.

What you need to do, is to modify the coordinate system before you start drawing. So just move the following two lines before the first beginPath() statement.

```
hh_context.translate(centerX, centerY);
hh_context.rotate((hh / 12) * 2 * Math.PI);
```

Comment: The following beginPath() statements are not working when I add them to the top of the code

Comment: It does work, it's just your image is out of the borders after transformation. I've made a working fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/0opvkryw/

Comment: hh_context.translate(-centerX, -centerY);
^This line was not in the original answer. That's why it was not drawing correctly. As vp_Arth pointed out, this line was necessary for moving coordinate system.